# Sprite Kit Physics Assertion failed: (typeA == b2_dynamicBody || typeB == b2_dynamicBody)

Tags: ios, physics, collision, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am trying to make a game with fully IOS 7 features using SpriteKit including Physics. So when user tabs to the screen, I am throwing a ball through some other balls (which are not moving and I set `dynamic=NO` for these target balls). What I want to do is:

- Immadiately stop the ball (I am using `resting=YES` for this)
- Switching categoryBitMask and contactTestBit mask from throwing ball to target ball's category / contactBitMask
- Stopping dynamics for this ball.

Everything is okay except one thing, when I am setting `dynamic=NO` inside `didBeginContact` (even any other functions like `update` or `didSimulatePhysics`) getting following error:

> Assertion failed: (typeA == b2_dynamicBody || typeB ==
>   b2_dynamicBody), function SolveTOI, file
>   /SourceCache/PhysicsKit_Sim/PhysicsKit-4.6/PhysicsKit/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.cpp,
>   line 670.

Alright I understand the reason 'cause calculations are still continuing about physics but somehow I have to set this.

So how can I stop dynamics programatically after collision / contact?

Comment: I solved my problem by just separating `collisionBitMask` and working with only `contactTestBitMask`. Means that I did not touch to `dynamic` property.

Comment: Found this great workaround: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462295/sprite-kit-failing-assertion-typea-b2-dynamicbody-typeb-b2-dynamicbod

Comment: I tried this method at first, it is working but occuring flicks if object is moving so fast.

Comment: Using a temp physics body *should* solve the problem.... I use it and my objects move fairly fast -- however, if you solved it already by manipulating collisionBitMas and contactTestBitMase then things are good :p

Comment: Yes Nolan, I already solved it by using collisionBitMask. At least it is better than increasing memory usage.