# SpriteKit: cannot change node position in contact callback

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a node with a dynamic physics body. And I would like to make it static and change its position when it comes in contact with another body.

I managed to make the body static with the solution provided in this question: [Sprite Kit failing assertion: (typeA == b2_dynamicBody || typeB == b2_dynamicBody)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462295)

However if I change the `position` property of the node in one of the contact callback methods (e.g `didBeginContact`) the new position is not taken into account.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: can you post the code that fails to update the position, as well as how you implemented the solution you linked to?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D the solution given by JKallio works fine (reassigning the physicsBody to its node)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in SpriteKit. (I was able to reproduce this problem with SpriteKit 7.1).

Here is a quick workaround:

```
- (void) didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
     contact.bodyB.node.position = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
     contact.bodyB.node.physicsBody = contact.bodyB.node.physicsBody; // <-- Add this line
}
```

Comment: It works fine. I just changed a bit the last line: `contact.bodyB.node.physicsBody = contact.bodyB.node.physicsBody;`

Answer (score 0):

JKallio's solution did not work for me (Xcode 7.2.1 on OS X 10.10.5, targeting iOS 8.1). I figured out that I was able to change the position in `update:` method, so I got around the bug by setting a flag in `didBeginContact` and changing the position in `update:`.

```
@implementation GameScene {
    SKNode *_victim;
    CGPoint _target;
}

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    _victim = nil;
}

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    _victim = contact.bodyB.node;
    _target = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
}

- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if (_victim != nil) {
        _victim.position = _target;
        _victim = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Note that `_victim` serves as both the node and the flag.

My solution is more complicated that JKallio's; try that one before coming for this.

Answer (score 0):

As another option for a workaround, I instead call a method in a `SKSpriteNode` subclass for the object I want to move, passing in that body. The position gets set correctly.

```
/* In GameScene.swift */

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let dotBody: SKPhysicsBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == 0b1 {
        dotBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        dotBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if let dot = dotBody.node as? Dot {
        dot.move()
    }        
}
```

Here is the Dot class:

```
import SpriteKit
class Dot : SKSpriteNode {
    let dotTex = SKTexture(imageNamed: "dot")
    init() {
        super.init(texture: dotTex, color: .clear, size: dotTex.size())
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: size.width / 2)
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0b1 << 1
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0b1
    }

    func move() {
        let reset = SKAction.run {
            self.position.x = 10000
        }
        self.run(reset)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```